# Voto de pergunta aceita não deveria contar na pontuação de uma tag?

Tags: novo-recurso, tags, reputação

O sistema de pontuação das tags é baseado nos votos (up/down), ou seja, se tiver uma pontuação de 20 em uma determinada tag, significa que a soma dos votos na sua reposta foram de 20.

Ok isso faz todo sentido mas, seguindo o modelo de reputação, uma resposta aceita, não deveria receber ao menos 1 ponto para as tags?

Acontece muito de o usuário quem fez a pergunta aceitar sua reposta e ela não ter votos (nem de quem perguntou, porque afinal ele já aceitou a resposta), isso significa que, apesar de a respostar ser útil ao menos a quem perguntou, ela não computa nenhum ponto de tag.

Apenas como exemplo, eu tenho duas respostas na tag `razor`, sendo uma aceita, mas não tenho nenhum ponto nessa tag:  [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:57220+[razor]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:57220%20[razor])

Apenas uma sugestão de melhoria, se fizer sentido pra comunidade, no universo de sugestões para o SO :)

Comment: Eu acredito que não, pois o autor da pergunta geralmente também pode positivar. Ele estaria passando a dar 2 pontos para a pessoa. Além disso aceitação não significa resposta certa, e sim que o autor gostou daquilo. Eu defendi em muitas ocasioes e repito, acredito que aceitação nao deveria nem deixar a reposta no topo. No máximo, se não for a 1a da lista, ter um link discreto na pergunta dizendo que o autor escolheu uma resposta mais abaixo como adequada. Votação reflete opinião de toda uma comunidade, aceitação é só de uma pessoa, e justo uma que tem grande chance de nem entender do assunto.

Comment: @Bacco Concordo que nem sempre o AP é o mais indicado para avaliar qual a melhor resposta, mas o voto positivo dele também conta para a pontuação da tag (ou seja, o voto de quem supostamente não sabe avaliar, mas conta mesmo assim). Sendo assim, a regra não poderia ser "se o AP votou **ou** aceitou, conta um ponto pra tag"? Isso evita os 2 pontos caso ele aceite e vote, mas dá pontuação de tag pros vários casos em que ele não votou porque não tem pontuação suficiente (ou porque não quis, ou não sabia que podia votar, etc).

Comment: @Bacco eu entendo, mas acho que no caso da pergunta em si é importante também levar em consideração se a resposta atendeu ao que quem perguntou precisava, afinal foi ele quem motivou as respostas, senão corremos o risco (que até acontece às vezes) de ter  de perguntas aleatórias "só para a comunidade responder", com o intuito de formar um banco de perguntas/respostas somente, e não sermos um "refúgio" para quem realmente tem dúvidas, que me parece ser o propósito inicial do SO, mas tb percebo que tem vezes que a resposta mais bem elaborada e aceita não é a escolhida

Comment: a ideia do @hkotsubo parece bem interessante, quem fez a pergunta só pode computar 1 pontos, seja pelo upvote ou pela resposta aceita, me parece bem justo

Comment: mas @Bacco seu ponto é interessante, talvez um sistema de peso talvez resolvesse no caso de rankear a resposta... algo como (estou só chutando ok) ter o dobro de votes+1, por exemplo, a resposta escolhida tem 2 upvotes, mas tem uma outra resposta que tem 5 upvotes, talvez ela pudesse ser classificada acima, ou o triplo, só palpitando aqui :)

Comment: gostaria de entender os downvotes, o que há tem ruim ou mal elaborado nessa pergunta?